# initializate array as argument when calling method

Tags: java, arrays, methods, parameters, arguments

Hi I'd like to ask if you can call method with not declared and initialized array in some value, but to call method without any array.

I know you can initialize array like this:

`int[] array={1,2,7,89,2,-5,0};`

but can you do something similar when calling method with array[] parameter like this:

original method `g.fillPolygon(int[] Xs,int[] Ys,int numberOfPoints);`

`g.fillPolygon({25,85,110,85,25,0}, {0,0,50,100,100,50}, 6);`

THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `array = {1,2,7,89,2,-5,0};` syntax is valid only when declaring & initializing the array **inline**. On the other hand, you can do this

```
g.fillPolygon(new int[]{25,85,110,85,25,0}, 
    new int[]{0,0,50,100,100,50}, 
    6);
```

& you can get rid of the array parameters.

Comment: Thanks finaly I know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

array initialization syntax can be used for methods with `new`  like

```
void m(int[] a){}
m(new int[]{1,2,3});
```